# JavaFX KeyCombination for Command+T (New Tab)

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I'm trying to make a key pressed listener for my browser app for Command+T to trigger opening a new tab in the same way that most actual browsers do it.

Looked up some possible solutions for this and it looks like I probably have to use `KeyCombination` however I can't find anything for the command key. So far, the closest I've found is Control+T.

```
private KeyCombination newTab = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.T, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
...
root.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (newTab.match(event))
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab());
});
```

I know this currently works fine but I really want to use command instead of control because it's much more natural and intuitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#SHORTCUT_DOWN).

> ### [`KeyCombination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html)
>
> ...
>
> The `shortcut` modifier is used to represent the modifier key which is used commonly in keyboard shortcuts on the host platform. This is for example `control` on Windows and `meta` (command key) on Mac. By using `shortcut` key modifier developers can create platform independent shortcuts. So the "Shortcut+C" key combination is handled internally as "Ctrl+C" on Windows and "Meta+C" on Mac.

From that documentation, it looks like they refer to "command" as "meta". If you don't want to use the cross-platform `SHORTCUT_DOWN` you can use [`KeyCombination.META_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html) instead.